# Unity - Auto completion fix for Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I don't know what started it - maybe an update to the Unity Engine or the Visual Studio Tools for Unity (because I can't remember that I've updated Visual Studio itself) - but since a couple of weeks, my Visual Studio auto completion got basically incompatible with Unity.

I used to write "void A" to tab-complete it to

```
void Awake() {

}
```

but now it get's auto-completed to

```
private void Awake() {

}
```

Has anyone got an idea what caused this and how to change it back? It just get's annoying to remove the 'private' access modifier every time I autocomplete a standard Unity method.

Comment: Although potentially annoying, is there any reason why this is causing problems? Methods are private by default, so `void Awake()` and `private void Awake()` should not result in any difference in your code execution...

Comment: Afaik it is not causing problems, but...habits. I guess you can relate, maybe when talking about whether the "{" has to be in the same line or in the next. Imagine your IDE suddenly switching from what you're used to. :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity Scripts edited in Visual studio don't provide autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597501/unity-scripts-edited-in-visual-studio-dont-provide-autocomplete)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The update changes some settings. I just noticed that now but don't have problems with it.

Go to *Tools* --> *Options*. Select *Tools for Unity* then change *Unity Messages scope* from *Private* to *Default*. Click *Ok* and exit.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, that's it! Thanks. :)