# Scripts stay "Miscellanous Files"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity 5.5.4p4 with Visual Studio 15.5.1 and I'm having trouble with the problem mentionned in this thread: [Problem explained here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597501/autocompletion-not-working-in-visual-studio)

I have readen all of the thread, I have tried **each** answers (these in the comments too) and nothing works.

I have uninstalled /reinstalled VS, VS Tools for Unity, it has changed nothing.
I am suspicious about the last Visual Studio Update that have introduced (again ?) this problem.

Comment: I doubt you tried *everything* from my answer. Did you try **Fix Part 4** from my answer? That should definitely fix your issue. How about **Fix Part 5:** which requires deleting some files?

Comment: Having tried all the answers from the linked question doesn't make your question any less of a duplicate.

Comment: @Programmer, thx for answering me.
About Fix Part 4, there is a difference. My files are already correctly added to the project but they stay "Miscellanous Files".
About Fix Part 5, It's the 1st thing I do before surrending and looking on stackoverflow. It changed nothing, VS generate the new solution / project with the same problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand part of your comment. Did "Fix Part 4" fix your Miscellanous Files? It should fix each individual ones that already exist...

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. :/
When I right click on my files in the solution explorer of VS, I just have "Exclude from project" so they are already included. 
So, I tried to exclude them and re-include them, and they are still considered as "Miscellanous Files". Did I miss something ?
I wonder if it's not the project generation that is broken due to the VS update.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with the Visual Studio Update Version 15.5.2.