# VS 2017 + Unity + Mac OS high sierra (10.13.4) symbolic links and aliases are not working

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017, macos-high-sierra

I am using VS 2017 on mac with Unity3d. I have a project where different files and folders are soft linked (aliased) in to the project folder. The problem is that VS doesn't index those files, meaning that there is no autocompletion or visibility of other classes outside the current open file. The projects builds without problems, but there is no support when typing. Before High Sierra I could use hard links and that worked fine, but since High Sierra has apple file system, which doesn't support hard links, so I had to use soft links. Did anybody had this issue or knows where to look and what to try?

Thanks!

Comment: Manually include the files to your project. See [Fix Part 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597501/autocompletion-not-working-in-visual-studio/42598927#42598927).  from my other post

Comment: Thanks @Programmer. I've tried your solution, all my files already in the project. The problem is if I have an alias folder inside the project folder, then it doesn't index them.