# Visual studio tools for Unity unavailable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

When I try to download Game development with Unity in VS installer its marked as unavailable:

[image]

So when I open script from unity it shows as miscellaneous file and auto complete isn't working for unity elements:

[image]

I tried many solutions like downloading unity tools for VS 2015 and installing it

Like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42598927/7336236

but its not showing in my External tools:

[image]

I also downloaded Nuget PackageManager but still not working

I'm using latest version of VS 15.7.1

Edit

The question isn't duplicate because I already tried the other answers like I mentioned above.

Comment: If you can't install Visual Studio Tools for Unity from VS, Google *"Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Unity"*. Download and install it. By the way, I think it should be included in Unity while installing Unity but if you missed that, that's fine. Just google it and download it.

Comment: i mentioned in the question i already did that

Comment: I thought you said "VS installer its marked as unavailable" which means you couldn't install it?

Comment: yeah that's why i mentioned that i tried to do it manually but still didn't work.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by manually, but if you have downloaded "Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Unity", I encourage you to install both Unity, VS15 and VS tool then re-install them. This time, install all of them from Unity installer and let Unity handle all of it.

Comment: by manually i meant i downloaded it from google like you said and like mentioned in the answer i linked above.
I'm asking for solution for VS17 if there is one.

Comment: Unity thinks OP is using Visual Studio 2017.  There is no "Visual Studio 2017 Tools for Unity" and the 2015 version won't install onto VS2017.  Unity tools are integrated with VS2017 which is why it's showing in the installer.  OP is in a state causing the "Unavailable" message.  No answers have addressed how to recover from this state.