# Visual Studio doesn't autocomplete or show suggestions on unity external dll

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was making an **external dll** (not Assembly-CSharp) for my game and I found problem. Code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class GOObj : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
    }
}
```

The problem is that the visual studio doesn't show suggestions related to methods like `Update`, `OnGUI` or `Awake` neither autocomplete them or change color of the method name to blue. That happened after updating Visual Studio 2017, how can I fix it?

[image: gif of the project.]

I have Visual Studio Tools For Unity installed.

Edit: This question is not a duplicate, it isn't miscallenous files.

Comment: Is the `Update` method a virtual method contained in the base class (`MonoBehaviour`)? What happens if you start typing `override`?

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597501/autocompletion-not-working-in-visual-studio

Comment: override shows me `GetHashCode()` `ToString()` `Equals(object o)`. Manually typing  `override void Update()` is giving me error. I seen the other question but it didn't helped me.

Comment: Close Unity an VS then reinstall Visual Studio Tools For Unity

Comment: I tried doing that before i posted this question here.

Comment: You did or tried? If you did then your only option now is restarting computer. If that still doesn't work then uninstall and install Visual Studio then install "Visual Studio Tools For Unity"

Comment: I did also i will do what you're saying me now.

Comment: Have you checked ALL the answers from the question I posted?

Comment: Yes, i tried all of them but none helped. Also it's an "external dll" that has reference to UnityEngine.dll

Comment: Visual Studio finished installing and i restarted computer. The auto completion still isn't working.