# C# code not letting me use functions in their libraries

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, libraries

This is my simple code - I'm using Visual Studio 2017, and assume the issue is with the libraries that contain the functions Input."" are not being found.

There is no auto complete, when I start to type Input."" and there are no colours indicating it's a prewritten function. Could anyone help?

I've been stuck trying to figure out how to make this work and I'm completely stalemated (btw even when I type 0.5f it does not colour up like it does when I watch other people code this).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horiztonal") > 0.5f)
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horiztonal") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime,0f,0f));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Input is a UnityEngine method, so if the includes are ther it should not show as error. try doing "assets/open c# project"

Comment: Check [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1585929/miscellaneous-files-making-scripts-not-work.html) for the solution. Most likely you have the same issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autocompletion not working in Visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597501/autocompletion-not-working-in-visual-studio)

Comment: the only errors I get is "the referenced script (unknown) on this behaviour is missing"

Comment: Thanks Ali, I think I just need to go through their solutions, and it should fix it. Looks like that guy did have the same problem as me.