# VisualStudio doesn't detect the Unity3D syntax

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Well, Visual Studio does not detect the Unity3D syntax at all. For example, when I type `Input.` it should normally be unity options, but it does not show me such. It does not even show me the colorful syntax of this. As if it was a plain text file and not a C#. Print Screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7P5LO.jpg

EDIT: Tools for unity are installed: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1fKE.png)

Comment: Sounds like the Unity tools weren't installed.

Comment: Is the `UnityEngine` namespace inclusded on the top of the file? I had this sometimes in the past as well .. for me it helped to A) close VS and Unity, start Unity and doubleclick a script -> VS finds the Unity dlls now B) if A didn't work: Close everything, remove anthing except the `Assets` and `ProjectSettings` folders, than open Unity and let it recompile.

Comment: I suspect the 3 lines above the top of the screenshot would give us a better idea of the problem.

Comment: KK I found an answer! This tutorial help me in my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597501/autocompletion-not-working-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, VS fails to recognizes Unity classes and libraries because there are compile errors. Try to compile your code and resolve any error.

Also you may want to open VS from Unity Editor by double-clicking on the script you want to modify. This may solve your issue. However all of these are not your fault. These are because of some issues with Unity plugin for VS.

Comment: Ye. Unity can open Visual Studio but as you say fails to recognizes classes

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed my issue by going into Unity preferences and making sure VS is selected and not open by file extension.

Comment: At least give an example to make lazy people's life easier. We're going to StackOverflow because we're procrastinators.