# How to setup Visual Studio for existing Unity project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have cloned an existing Unity project from git on a new machine, and the source does not include `*.sln` or `*.csproj`.

I have also downloaded Visual Studio from Unity Hub, but the editor doesn't work with Unity:

1. VS doesn't recognize Unity components
2. Unity doesn't update VS project (new scripts not recognized in VS)

[image]

I have selected VS as external tool for Unity, as shown here:

[image]

I also installed anything VS suggests (Mono, and a few plugins, etc). What's still missing?

The VS version is 7.7.4 and Unity is 2019.02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed when I happened to re-open the project inside Unity:

> Asset > Open C# Project

References:

1. [Autocompletion not working in Visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597501/autocompletion-not-working-in-visual-studio)
2. https://answers.unity.com/questions/1451377/autocomplete-in-visual-studio-wont-work-please-hel.html

Comment: Also install Visual Studio Tools for Unity if you haven't already. This will let you, for example, make persistent changes to the generated project files.