# Unity wont create a project, just a cs file which prevents IntelliSense from working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, intellisense

everytime I create a C# Script in Unity

[image]

it creates the file without creating a new project or adding the file to an already existing project.

[image]

Since the new created file is a blank cs, IntelliSense wont activate, which is really annoying.

I already tried creating a new C#-Project and pulling it into Unity, but projects that are created out of Unity do not inherit from MonoBehaviour. Also, the Start and Update methods arent created from the beginning.

I would love to have all my in Unity created C#-Scripts in a project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autocompletion not working in Visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597501/autocompletion-not-working-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio Tools for Unity wasnt installed.

Comment: Hi actopozipc, so glad to hear that your issue is solved and please mark it as answer, that will help others to easier search it, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have Visual Studio Tools for Unity installed and sometimes I ran into this issue. One thing that I do, instead of double clicking the .cs file is this.[Click on open C# project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlwyV.jpg) This will force Unity to create a project if one doesn't exist, after that when you create a new script, don't double click on it to open it. You have to open it in your visual studio project. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit -> Preferences -> External Tools

- Select Visual Studio as external script editor
- Then click on regenerate project files