# Turn on unity code snippets in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, intellisense, code-snippets

I've installed Unity, VS-2019, Net4.x.

After all, Intellisense know what when I write "Rig..." I mean RigidBody, but It doesn't autocomplete methods like OnTriggerExit() or even Start() and Update().
How can I enable it?

I've specified VS executable in unity preferences, net4.x and reloaded both unity and VS many times.

```cs
public class SomeScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private Rigidbody rb;
    void Start ()
    {
        this.rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        //this line autocompleted well
    }

    void OnTrigger... // doesn't autocomplete
}
```

Comment: which Unity version are you using? Some older versions are not fully supported with VS2019

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this results from the Incompatibility between Unity and VS version. So make sure you use Unity2019 with VS2019, and update them to latest version.

Check the `external tools setting` in Unity, make sure the `external script editor` in it is set as corresponding VS version. (For your situation, choose the VS2019)

Then you can check if this issue persists after unloading and reloading the project in Solution explorer.

Also, I suggest you can follow the detailed steps from [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42598927/10910450) to trouble-shooting and resolve this issue. Hope it helps:)