# Unity - Cursor.visible not recognised by Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

For some reason, Cursor.visible is not [recognised](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPVWr.png). I've restarted my PC and it doesn't fix the issue. Maybe it's an error with my version, I'm running Unity 2019.3.4f1.

Let me know if you have a solution.

Comment: and what happens if you ignore it and decide you know better and save the file and go back to unity, does unity agree with it?

Comment: Is the error displayed in the editor ?

Comment: Unity also gives the error- "Cursor does not contain a definition for visible" .https://imgur.com/a/vXj1Apb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may  be what you're looking for. Sometimes Unity namespaces don't show up in Visual Studio. My fix when this happens is to go to the parent Asset folder, create a blank new C# script, and double click. Here are a ton of alternative solutions:

[Autocompletion not working in Visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597501/autocompletion-not-working-in-visual-studio)

If that's your problem, this question is definitely a duplicate