# Unity function autocompletion doesn't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

My unity general autocompletion works but when it gets to functions it says: "No suggestions".
Video: https://gyazo.com/0e86d36786a4f75df6d0471e6900b8aa
Unity version: 2019.4.1f1
Visual Studio 2017 Version: 15.9.24
I have installed Unity Game Development package in visual studio.
I have selected the External Script editor in unity to be Visual Studio 2017.
I have installed .NET package in Visual studio.

Comment: Is there autocompletionf or other unity components? (transform etc.)

Comment: yes, for other unity components there is autocompletion, only function autocompletion doesn't work.

Comment: did function auto-completion work before?

Comment: yes, it worked before

Comment: Did you update to a newer version of Unity recently.

Comment: no, i didn't update to a newer version but i skiped a newer version

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem very often, you can try to rebuild your project

- Close VStudio
- Then in Unity menu Assets => Reimport all (or delete the Library folder before launching Unity), it almost always fixes my autocomplete issues.

If it doesn't work, you got a lot of things to try in this answer => https://stackoverflow.com/a/42598927/6469334
Some tricks may be outdated, but some others are still common struggle with VS.