# The Unity Scripts edited in Visual studio don't provide autocomplete...2020

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

just like the title Unity Scripts edited in Visual studio don't provide autocomplete. i am trying to make a rigid body and as you can see it doesn't recognize it, some help? By the way i can't change the "External script editor" to something else but "open file by extension:

[image: c# writing]

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about the C# programming language, or the Javascript-derived deprecated UnityScript programming language?

Comment: C# programming language

Comment: Have you tried visual studio code. I created an extension method yesterday and it was picked up by the other scripts immediately

Comment: no, what do you mean? how did you create it?

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't automagically generate autocompletes for you, you'll need the [Visual Studio Tools for Unity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/visual-studio-tools-for-unity?view=vs-2019) extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your installation of Visual Studio is probably missing the Visual Studio Tools for Unity extension.
Try this installation guide: [Get started with Visual Studio Tools for Unity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/getting-started-with-visual-studio-tools-for-unity?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 0):

There is a previous forum that provides guidance on this issue which is still relevant in 2021:

[Unity Scripts edited in Visual studio don't provide autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597501/unity-scripts-edited-in-visual-studio-dont-provide-autocomplete)

One solution that worked for me that was not in that forum was going to the Solution Explorer tab in Visual Studios. Right click the solution and hit resolve errors. This may fix the issue.