# How do i enable auto fill option in Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, syntax, autocomplete

I just started game development on unity and wanted to write some code in Visual Studio 2019 but when I started typing some code no syntax was being shown below.
I mean when I write a dot in c# a dropdown menu should appear with commonly used lines with their definition.

Sorry for using bad terms I hope you are understanding and I want this to help me in C#.

Comment: maybe you can use unity hub to install visual studio

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is go to visual studio installer and download tools for unity, if that doesn't work, inside unity navigate to edit > preferences then under external tools make sure you have visual studio selected and not open by file extension.

Answer (score -1):

VS-code is more better if you are starting out and it is light weight.
Install VS-Code from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

If you mean to say you want to enable unity-intellisense, then in your unity editor go under edit > preferences. See the image below.
Select VS-Code as your ide and for generate .csproj files uncheck all and check only registry packages, then hit regenrate .csproj files. It will take time to generate them.
In Vs-Code install the c-sharp extension and reload the window. Then you should be ready to start using it for game developement in unity.
[preferences image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROfFz.png)
[c-sharp extension image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3hj9.png)

But if you want for Visual Studio only install Visual Studio depedencies from unity hub while installing the version

[unityhub installation for visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NJaJ.png)

Please check the images and link given too

Comment: Thank You 
but First i downloaded VS code it was bugged out on my desktop i reinstalled it many times but i didnt work but anyways thankyou.

Comment: no only select that one option and deselect rest all so you can install only the dependencies for Visual Studio, do this only for those version which you have installed the build options already

Comment: LTS means life term support which means it is more efficient then others

Comment: please upvote my answer as i am new to answering at stackoverflow

Comment: also answer here too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597501/unity-scripts-edited-in-visual-studio-dont-provide-autocomplete?rq=1