# Can anyone help me with the loadingSceneIndex issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

does anyone know where the error is? I've been looking for various solutions but I didn't get what I wanted

```
public static void LoadScene(int levelNum)
{
    Application.backgroundLoadingPriority = ThreadPriority.High;
    sceneToLoad = levelNum;
    SceneManager.LoadScene(loadingSceneIndex);
}
```

Eror : Assets\Script AR\LoadingScreenManager.cs(35,32): error CS0103: The name 'loadingSceneIndex' does not exist in the current context

and one more problem this one

```
private void StartOperation(int levelNum)
{
    Application.backgroundLoadingPriority = loadThreadPriority;

    operation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(levelNum, loadSceneMode);

    if (loadSceneMode = LoadSceneMode.Single)
        operation.allowSceneActivation = false;
}
```

Eror : Assets\Script AR\LoadingScreenManager.cs(91,13): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode' to 'bool'

Comment: have you check if you add yourscene in build setting->scenes in build?

Comment: apparently not, how to do it?

Comment: go to file build settings and add your scenes there

Comment: is there a tutorial?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildSettings.html

Comment: click add open scenes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first error happens because the variable `loadingSceneIndex` doesn't exist. You should plug the scene you want to load into the LoadScene function like this:

   `SceneManager.LoadScene(levelNum);`

   That way the LoadScene function knows which scene to load.
2. The second error happens because in you're if statement expects a bool, but plug in `loadSceneMode = LoadSceneMode.Single`. That is defining loadSceneMode. Instead, use `loadSceneMode == LoadSceneMode.Single` instead because that will return a bool.

Note: Have you looked into using something like Intellisense so your editor can detect these errors for you. If you are using Visual Studio, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597501/unity-scripts-edited-in-visual-studio-dont-provide-autocomplete) might help.