# Not getting autcomplete for Unity in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019

I know this has already been addressed many times, but really I have tried everything that I found and I just can't get the autocomplete to work. I first tried VS Code but I could not get it to work, then I opened Visual Studio and tried everything I found in different forums but nothing.

I have already tried:

- Downloading Unity tools for Visual Studio
- Regenerating project files
- Setting Visual Studio as preference in Unity.
- Redownloading Visual Studio.

I think I may have missed something in the External tools window, but I am not sure about what.

**External Tools Window**
[image]

**My editor with the file structure**
[image]

Comment: Just to be sure: You opened the script by double clicking it inside of Unity?

Comment: Yes, I clicked the script through unity.

Comment: Maybe you can find the solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597501/unity-scripts-edited-in-visual-studio-dont-provide-autocomplete#:~:text=From%20Visual%20Studio%2C%20go%20to,be%20available%20in%20Visual%20Studio)