# How do i get rich predictions working for libs?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am going through a unity c# visual studio tutorial and its showing rich predictions with libs on the tutorial but on my software it isn't showing rich predictions on the libs. code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shape : MonoBehaviour
{
    Material shapeMaterial;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597501/unity-scripts-edited-in-visual-studio-dont-provide-autocomplete

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity Scripts edited in Visual studio don't provide autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597501/unity-scripts-edited-in-visual-studio-dont-provide-autocomplete)