# Unity and Visual Studio IntelliSense auto-completion issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I want to preface my problem by stating that I tried everything on this post:

[Unity Scripts edited in Visual studio don't provide autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597501/unity-scripts-edited-in-visual-studio-dont-provide-autocomplete?newreg=0601b07bc66d429db74e050bd8821ee9)

And that auto-completion work for things like "Vector3.up", but I don't have recommendation when I want to write, for example: private void OnTriggerEnter(), I write until "OnTri" and nothing pops up as it should.

Now, I use Unity 2017.3f1 for the purpose of a lesson, and Visual Studio Community 2022, with Unity tools installed, and vs 2022 as my default engine on Unity external tools.

I used to have my Unity version set on the most recent build before I downgraded my whole project to the version I use now, which triggered visual studio to make me download the target sdk ( .NET 4.6 ) which I did.

My other project ( latest version of Unity ) have IntelliSense and auto-completion ( related to Unity stuff ) who works just fine, so it must come from my Unity 2017 Project, but I can't figure a way to make IntelliSense work completely with the script of this project.

I don't know if this will help finding the problem, but when I right click I can't even use Unity short messages, the  option doesn't show (on my 2017 project, works fine with most recent project).

I use the same SDK as the one in Unity Player Configuration... (which vs asked me to install at the launch anyway).

I reimported everything, did everything in the post I linked above...

I'm lost.

Comment: Have you tried going to preferences>external editor, and making sure the version is correct, hit "regenerate project files" 

Also, does visual studio say the name of the project, or "Misc files" (like in the answer you linked?) Just checking all the bases.

Comment: Also - you dont have any vs plugins, like resharper do you? some stuff can overwrite intellisense

Comment: Try Ctrl+Shift+M

Comment: I already tried everything y'all mentioned, it didn't work... And no, i don't have any plug-in