# Learning Unity - How do I get autocomplete like in this video?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm watching this video to get an idea of how to start using Unity:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwZpJzpE2lQ&t=3579s
If you go to 59:59 you can see that after he pulled the RiggidBody component, he's able to get a dropdown menu of preloaded/recommended code to add.
When I try using Unity and Visual Studio for C# I'm not getting this dropdown menu of recommendations.
Anyone know how I can turn this on? I feel like that would be a great way to play around and see what C+ has to offer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity Scripts edited in Visual studio don't provide autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597501/unity-scripts-edited-in-visual-studio-dont-provide-autocomplete)

Answer (score 1):

This may happen from number of causes.

On Unity, look for Edit>Preferences>External Tools.

On Visual Studio Installer, make sure you installed "Game Development with Unity" package.

Checkout this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGeMTwvmU6M&ab_channel=ChargerGames