# I can't use Rigidbody2D command in visual studio

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to develop a game with c# on Unity, but when I try to use the rigidbody2d command, the command does not appear on visual studio. I chose visual studio from the external script editor in the external tools section over Unity, but my problem was still not resolved. I installed Unity game development plugins for Visual Studio but my problem did not get fixed again.

Comment: I think this thread cover all the major problems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597501/unity-scripts-edited-in-visual-studio-dont-provide-autocomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stackoverflow thread cover most of the problems:
[Unity Scripts edited in Visual studio don't provide autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597501/unity-scripts-edited-in-visual-studio-dont-provide-autocomplete)

If that's not enough, think about adding information such as the Unity / Visual Studio version and other important information.

For my part, I switch to VSCode for my Unity project, the installation is longer but you have more flexibility.

Comment: i made same like you, thanks it solved!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by doing the following steps:

- go to: "Edit" > Preferences > External Tools > Select the External Script Editor "Visual Studio"