# Why is visual studio not giving me a dropdown menu whenever I type anything out?

Tags: c#, colors

I didnt change anything, I just put the dot down and it doesnt give me any dropdown menu or options to do with it. Also, as I type things down, most of them are not being colored in visual studio. the code works fine in unity tho so, what gives?[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BO9y4.png)

I tried serching it up already and could not find anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

**Fix 1:**

It sounds like you don't have the Visual Studio Tools for Unity extension installed/running. Try following this quick guide on installing, setting up, and updating the extension.

Link: [Visual Studio Tools for Unity - Quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/gamedev/unity/get-started/getting-started-with-visual-studio-tools-for-unity?pivots=windows)

**Fix 2:**

If that still is working, and you are not getting any suggestions/auto-complete options, read through this answer here [Unity Scripts edited in Visual studio don't provide autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597501/unity-scripts-edited-in-visual-studio-dont-provide-autocomplete)

The question is from six years ago, but the answerer went into great detail on different steps to fix any problems.

Hope this helps, and happy coding :)

Comment: thank you for this, happy coding to you as well