# Autocomplete not appearing in VS Code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

While I was coding a script for a game object in unity, I noticed the absence of autocomplete that appear while coding.

For instance : `gameObject.[list of possible commands]`

Visual Studio Code will still suggest me commands while coding normal C#, or Python. But when I want to use commands which are used to change something which concerns anything inside unity (For example : the name of the gameObject, or the velocity of the gameObject), no options will appear. This issue does not occur in Visual Studio ONLY in VS Code.

This is what I see : [image]

As you can see no dropdown of suggestions/options.

PS: I have set the external script editor in unity to VS Code.
PS 2 : I am not using VS Code in Restricted Mode.
PS 3: I have restarted Unity and it still didn't fix the problem.

How can I fix that and make the dropdown list appear ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity Scripts edited in Visual studio don't provide autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597501/unity-scripts-edited-in-visual-studio-dont-provide-autocomplete)

Comment: I tried what they suggested, yet it didn't work

Comment: Be sure to put what you have tried already in your question. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/76534533/11107541 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/76438993/11107541

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution to my problem.
Just go to VS Code Extensions and download the "C# Extension pack".
Now autocomplete works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. Installing the [.NET Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-pack) has the autocomplete working fine and as expected.