# Autocomplete not working for C# in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I've just decided to start learning c# and unity, and have found a good course to follow on youtube. But after having followed the steps to set up Visual Studio Code (on mac), I'm still not getting the same autocomplete options for c# as the person in the video. The video tells me that the autocomplete is a game changer and that I should not continue with the course until I have it set up.

I have downloaded .NET x64 (arm) and mono-project, I have Microsoft's C# extension in visual studios, and I have disabled 'Omnisharp: Use Modern Net in Code settings' (All steps as per the video I am following).
This is the autocomplete in the video:
[image]

But as you can see I'm not getting any auto complete unless I type a letter after the '.'
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpDP4.png)

Comment: Use CTRL + SPACE

Comment: related (dup?): https://stackoverflow.com/q/76534533/11107541

Answer (score 1):

Try installing Dot net framework 4.7.1. The update visual studio code and Unity core is not compatible. For mac you need mono and dot net SDK too.

Few tweaks seem to fix it. Here is a step by step guide to [VScode Autocomplete](https://vionixstudio.com/2021/11/02/unity-visual-studio-code/).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. I managed to fix it by following this YouTube tutorial: "Set up Visual Studio Code with UNITY, MAC, and INTELLISENSE WORKING 2023"

Problem seemed to be that OmniSharp wasn't running properly.
I had to download the (Stable Channel) instead of the (Visual Studio channel) version of mono.