# Visual Studio Code Mac, Intellisense c# works then refreshes and stops with some projects

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

Edit with more info:

So I have been wracking my brains trying to troubleshoot this.

Latest VS Code update and some projects they open, I see the colour coding for intellisense and then it refreshes and removes the colours and the intellisense doesn't work. Not all projects.

I reinstalled the previous VS Code but it still does it.

I'm stuck as to how I troubleshoot this. I googled and saw reference to log files for the c# extension (where I believe the intellisense is)but I can't see logs on the Mac version. Also I can't tell if the code is running in the back.

What I would really appreciate is some ideas on how I can troubleshoot this, what I should be looking for and where?

The intellisense is not working for both dot net core and my types.

I cannot see why in some projects and not in others. I cannot see any differences in config (I mean they are different projects, some azure functions and some dot net core websites)

VSCode Mac is version 1.81.0 and I have reinstalled the 1.80 versions. The c# extension is v2.0.328.

What I have noticed is actually a difference of behaviour.

Within a project the intellisense works with the classes just for that project. It does not work for dot net SDK or any other projects that are reference. It was working last week for all these. Regressing didn't change that, so either I have not manage to clear everything correctly (removed code folder in application support and installed VS Code older version - it acts like it's a fresh install)

I am using dotnet 6, not 7.

I have a folder which contains 4 subfolders. Each subfolder is a c# project. One dotnet mvc website and 3 class libraries. The dotnet mvc website .proj file references the 3 other class libraries.

This set up has been running for over a year without issue.

I just can't work out what's changed...

help!
Paul

Comment: Before anything else, clearly learn what are the version numbers of your VS Code and all C# related extensions. Edit the question to include them.

Comment: try installing older versions of your C# extension to see if an older one doesn't have the issue. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/42626065/11107541.

Comment: @LexLi I have edited the message with more details

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76438993/11107541, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/337

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Linux.

I installed an older version of the C# Dev Kit (0.2.100) extension and it started to work.

Then I updated it to the latest one (0.3.21) and it still worked.

Just uninstalling/reinstalling the extension did not work for me. I really had to switch to an older version before reverting to the latest one.