# C# v2 language server not working in Visual Studio Code for Unity & macOS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, installation

Installing Unity's new VS Code (macOS) extension for VS Code (v0.9.0) requires upgrade to C# (from 1.26 to v2.0.328) as well as C# Dev Kit extensions, the result is that C# Dev Kit causes the 'Use Omnisharp' setting to be ignored ("This option will not be honored with the C# Dev Kit installed").  With this in effect, a project's C# (Unity) code is not processed for compile errors or warnings -- which is an obvious pain.

The C# server is doing at least some processing since the `X references` messages appear everywhere:

[image: The C# server is doing at least some processing since the X references messages appear everywhere]

Meanwhile, the only C# language server output:

[image: Meanwhile, the only C# lang server output]

If you're not aware, Unity C# support is a different animal than normal C# projects in VS Code.

UPDATE: this appears to be an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/337).

Comment: C# is currently at version 11.0 - not 2.0 - and there is no "version 1.26" of C# either (and the VSCode C# Extension [is currently at version 0.4.2](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csdevkit)) - so I don't know what you're referring to.

Comment: @Dai these are the versions of the VS Code extensions

Comment: see the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/a/76850404/11107541

Comment: @starball indeed, appreciate the link.  Sadly, the new [Unity extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioToolsForUnity.vstuc) requires [C# Dev Kit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csdevkit), apparently locking in this issue of OmniSharp getting ignored -- which I don't know how is getting past testing.  Only guess is they aren't testing on macOS which seems rather negligent.  Unity's prev VSC debugger has been deprecated for a year so was really trying to get the new one to work.

Comment: Appreciate the lead brother @starball -- yes, had seen that a few months back and to those who haven't seen it: downloading the "Stable Channel" (grey download box) is key nugget!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Autocomplete not working for C# in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76438993/autocomplete-not-working-for-c-sharp-in-visual-studio-code) (this is a customary message for closing as a duplicate, which I think we should do now that we know that one of the answers there helps you)