# Fail to load Unity project in Vscode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, environment

I'm using Unity 2021.3.28f version.
An error appears when I open VSCode from Unity, and the project can't load, resulting in autofill not working. How can I fix this?

```
`*[warning] The project file 'c:\Users\User\Unity\My project\Assembly-CSharp.csproj' is in unsupported format (for example, a traditional .Net Framework project). It need be converted to new SDK style to work in C# Dev Kit.*
*[error] Failed to load project 'c:\Users\User\Unity\My project\Assembly-CSharp.csproj'. One or more errors occurred. (This project is not supported in C# Dev Kit.)*`
```

I have intaill C#, C# dev kit, Unity Code Snippets, .NET Extension Pack

Checked that VSCode is selected in Unity as the external script editor

Turned off Omnisharp Modern NET usage

Someone has similar problem, But after trying it I still have the same issue.
[Unity Intellisense with VSCode not suggesting/autofilling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76534533/unity-intellisense-with-vscode-not-suggesting-autofilling)

I'm on window 11

I download .NET framework 4.7.1 developer pack and
.NET SDK 6.0

Comment: Try "omnisharp.projectLoadTimeout: 600" in settings.json.

Comment: The ms instructions dont include devkit. Have you tried the ms vscode and unity instructions?

Comment: possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76944652/visual-studio-code-intellisense-does-not-work-correctly-with-unity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solve it ;)
I simply removed ALL my Visual Studio Code extensions in the directory C:\Users\User.vscode\extensions and re-installed the C# extension. It worked.

Update:

After installing the "IntelliCode for C# Dev Kit" extension, which automatically installed another .NET extension, I encountered the same problem. It seems like this combination of extensions may be causing the issue.
That .NET extension can't be uninstalled normally so I clear my extension again.

Comment: Thanks! I had to remove the whole C# Dev Kit extension, which meant I had to remove the Unity extension by MS. But after that I didn't have to remove any other extensions. I just reloaded the window with CTL + SHIFT + P "Developer: Reload Window" and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the Visual Studio Code Editor package and updating Visual Studio Editor in Unity Package Manager

Comment: I did not quite understand this comment when I first read it but it it basically correct (see me answer)

Answer (score 2):

The fixes here where not working for me. If you run into this problem, heres is how I was able to fix it:

Go to the Package Manager:

- uninstall the Visual Studio **Code** EditorPackage  (The one with Code is the depricated one)
- install the Visual Studio Editor Package at least version 2.0.20 and **ONLY keep this package**

Go to Preferences -> External Tools

- Select Visual Studio Code  as the editor (probably was set wrong because of the old Code Editor Package)
- Press the Regenerate Project Files Button