# Visual Studio Code intellisense does not work correctly with Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I am using Unity 2021.3.29 and Visual Studio Code 1.81.1. I tried setting Visual Studio Code as the Unity C# editor by following the guide https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity. This is also what people on YouTube seems to be doing.

The problem I am facing is that when I first open a script through Unity it opens Visual Studio Code and it seems to recognize Unity code (as I am used of seeing it in e.g. Visual Studio 2019) but then 4-5 seconds later it seems to lose some connection. Please see before and after images below. I am getting no errors in console or anywhere, it just doesn't seem to recognize Unity things like InputField anymore and similar.

Last image is the Extensions I have active for the project if that helps.

**How can I fix Visual Studio Code to work with Unity?**

When it first fires up Visual Studio Code:
[image]

After around 4-5 seconds:
[image]

Extensions for Visual Studio Code:

[image]

Comment: If I remember correctly I had to change the root folder of VSCode to the root folder of the Unity Project. So one folder above the Assets folder.

Comment: @pixlhero, I am not entirely sure what you mean. In Explorer in Visual Studio Code I do have the Project name at top, then Assets, then my scripts.I used the Open as C# project from Unity.

Comment: then it's already setup. I think I also switched to omnisharp until the extension isn't in preview anymore.

Comment: for switching to omnisharp, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/76850403/11107541

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of discussion about IntelliSense-related issues recently in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/329. One user there [has written a part-way TL;DR](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/329#issuecomment-1675794278). I'll try my hand at it as well.

You're not the only one who observes this problem. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/329#issuecomment-1668036903. This other user has what sounds like the same issue, and they found that if they configure a default solution for the VS Code workspace, then the issue is resolved. Another user also found this to be the solution for them: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/329#issuecomment-1666870206. Ex. in .vscode/[settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"dotnet.defaultSolution": "path/to/your/solution/file/goes/here"
```

Another user in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/329#issuecomment-1668136038 found that they had to  right click the project in the Solution Explorer and click "clean" there every time they re-open VS Code.

Another user solved their issue by a lengthier process involving updating a VS Code package and regenerating project files, and using pre-release versions of related VS Code extensions. You can find their writeup [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/329#issuecomment-1666656455).

There's also (at the time of this writing), [a known bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/333) where having the Unity Package Netcode for Entities crashes the Language Server Protocol providing code completion.