# Vscode not loading Unity C# projects properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I installed the required extensions for vscode using `Unity` extension from Microsoft, which automatically installs extensions like `C#` and `C# Dev Kit`.

I first got an error that says

```
Failed to load project "c:\users\...\Assembly-CSharp.csproj'
is in unsupported format (for example, a traditional .NET Framework project).
It need be converted to new SDK style to work in C# Dev Kit.
```

I then converted it by adding the following code on top of the `.csproj` files

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Then it Worked. But is missing important components such as `System.Math.PI`

Showing the error `'System.Math'` does not contain a definition for 'PI' CS0117`

Comment: why would you use System.Math when unity provides Mathf.PI ?

Comment: possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76534533/11107541 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/76723267/11107541

Comment: @BugFinder It has nothing to do with me using that or this. The problem is that the project is opening without issue in visual studio, but not in visual studio code

Comment: where did I say it was the reason it wasnt working?  its a question.

Comment: It also said `Mathf` didn't contain definition for `PI` too. It was not loading it in both `System` and `Mathf`. It was a general issue loading the project file properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had issues with `VSCode` and `Microsoft's Unity` extension over the summer and in October (both on Windows and MacOS).

[These were the specific steps](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/329#issuecomment-1679677481) that helped me solve the issue in the past.

If it still isn't working, try a fresh installation with an empty `Workspace` and `User` `settings.json`. By that point something most likely will have fixed your issue.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

The problem was because `Visual Studio Editor` was stuck at version `2.0.18`, While it had to be updated to `2.0.22` . So, I unlocked and updated it.

Steps:

1. Window >> Package Manager
2. Search `Visual Studio Editor`
3. Click `Unlock`
4. Go to `Version history` tab
5. Update to the latest, `2.0.22` at the time of writing

**This solves it**
And You will find `Visual Studio Code [version]` with the [version] included in `Edit >> Preference >> External Tools >> External Script Editor`, where you can choose visual studio code and click `Regenerate project files`

More info [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/329)

Comment: That is my first step under "These were the specific steps". Not sure how this wasn't helpful to you.

Comment: Yes they were helpful. The github issue you mentioned was helpful too. I am marking yours as the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Woo! Glad the link helped! It was a really frustrating problem I had to go through as well (As an aside, the extension's intellisense also randomly stopped working one day a month ago, which required a full solution refresh. Since then I went ahead and disabled VSCode's auto update for extensions and for the application... but hopefully this is never a future problem for you). Ideally the updates to the Unity extension are more streamlined in the future. *fingers-crossed*